# php dosnt post a html selected <option>

Tags: php

So when i press submit every other field with input is printed, but selected option tag isnt printed in html, since option values are stored in an array..

select forms :

```
       <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" name="from">
            <option selected disabled>--Isvykimo vieta</option>
            <?php foreach($cities as $city):?>
            <option value='' style="color:black;"><?=$city;?></option>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" name="destination">
            <option selected disabled>--Keliones tikslas</option>
            <?php foreach($destinations as $destination):?>
            <option value='' style="color:black;"><?=$destination;?></option>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </select>
    </div>
```

and when i try to post

```
    <div class="ticket">
    <?php if(isset($_POST['send'])) ?>
    <div class="ticketInfo">
        <h5><?php echo htmlentities($_POST['names']);?> <?php echo htmlentities($_POST['lastName']);?></h5>
        <p>From: <?=  $_POST['from'];?> To:<?= $_POST['destination'];?></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

from to is just left blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <option value="<?=$city;?>" style="color:black;"><?=$city;?></option>
```

your value of input was empty, try like this please